# Read Perl JSON structure

Tags: json, perl

I get the JSON from request:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'); 
print "-------------------**------------------- \n";
my $content = $response->{content};
print $content->[0]->{name};
```

Response:

```
    [  
   {    
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",    "username": "Bret",    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
      "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",      "zipcode": "92998-3874",      "geo": {        "lat": "-37.3159",
      "lng": "81.1496"      }    },    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",    "website": "hildegard.org",
      "company": {
          "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
          "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
          "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
      }
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
      "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
          "lat": "-43.9509",
          "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
  }
]
```

How to read every content of the json return variable. I've tried this:
`print $content->[0]->{name};`
, but return nothing.

How to read through the JSON structure of perl?

Comment: You will have to show us what's in the content. Is it just plain text, undecoded JSON? What happens if you `print` that variable?

Comment: I've updated the code to print the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable contains a *string* that represents a data structure in the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/). You need to convert it to a Perl data structure in order to use traverse it in Perl. At this point, it's just a bunch of text, and HTTP::Tiny does not care what kind of data it returns.

Core Perl brings the [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) module [starting from version 5.13.9 (with the 5.14 release)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#New-Modules-and-Pragmata).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP 'decode_json';
use Data::Printer;

my $json = qq({ "foo" : "bar" });

my $decoded = decode_json($json);
p $decoded;
print $decoded->{foo};
```

This will output:

```
\ {
    foo   "bar"
}
bar
```

If you've got a newer Perl and have some other stuff installed, you probably also have [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS), which will pick the fastest JSON parser available automatically.

---

Now if you wanted your user agent to know how to do this in multiple places, you can easily create a sub class. I've done a rudimentary implementation here. Save it in a new file `HTTP/Tiny/DecodeJSON.pm` in the right folder. I would place it under `lib` in your script's directory.

```
.
├── lib
│   └── HTTP
│       └── Tiny
│           └── DecodeJSON.pm
└── script.pl
```

I would also suggest adding extensive error handling.

```
package HTTP::Tiny::DecodeJSON;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP 'decode_json';
use parent 'HTTP::Tiny';

# we need this to not throw a warning in HTTP::Tiny::_agent()    
use constant VERSION => '0.01';

sub get_json {
    my $self = shift;
    my $res = $self->get(@_);

    # add error handling here ...

    return decode_json $res->{content};
}

1;
```

You can then reuse it wherever you like. To use it in your script, you need to add the `lib` directory to the list of directories that Perl looks for it's modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

use lib 'lib';    
use HTTP::Tiny::DecodeJSON;

my $decoded = HTTP::Tiny::DecodeJSON->new->get_json(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
);
p $decoded;
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I worry that your example of subclassing may be copied verbatim without any understanding. It's a valid technique, but perhaps it would be better to write the module as a separate `.pm` file instead of just recommending it, as I have found multiple `package` declarations in a source file are a common source of confusion. *"Why is there no `use HTTP::Tiny::DecodeJSON`"* is the most common one, and people's attempts to do the same thing often fail because of a lack of understanding of the scope of pragmas.

Comment: @Borodin how about this?

Comment: That's excellent. I could complain about `Data::Printer` not producing executable Perl, and being useless within IDEs or when `STDOUT` is directed to a file, but that's irrelevant! I never really know whether people need to be told how to "create a file called `HTTP/Tiny/DecodeJSON.pm` within the `@INC` directories" but your explanation is very clear. Please don't think that you must go along with any criticisms that I come up with: I'm no oracle, and they're meant to be another point of view.

Comment: @Borodin I only go along when I agree with criticism or suggestions for improvements. I don't agree with your dislike of Data::Printer, so I will happily keep using that. :)

Comment: That's fine. I'm old-fashioned anyway, and coloured text in a command window looks more bizarre than it should. I may consider something like `use if -t STDIN, 'Data::Printer'` (but `p` would need to be aliased appropriately) otherwise you're going to see VT52 escape sequences where they don't make sense. Do you really run everything from the command line, rather from an IDE or editor that allows you to run the code you're working with?

Comment: @Borodin I work with Komodo IDE on Ubuntu. It just works with DDP, there's no problem with the colors. It's smart enough to know if it's in terminal I believe, or my IDE eats the escape sequences. This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f90Q7.png

Comment: I would also mention that Mojo::UserAgent as a non-core alternative to HTTP::Tiny, has built in JSON decoding functionality, which actually uses Cpanel::JSON::XS in recent versions if you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

[**simbabque** has explained a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52442016/622310),
and it is useful to have an example of subclassing [`HTTP::Tiny`](https://perldoc.pl/HTTP::Tiny). I would add the following

- I believe that [`Cpanel::JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS), despite its convoluted name, is the superior JSON module on CPAN
- There is no `$content->[0]->{name}` element in the data returned from that URL, although I imagine that is because you are working on it. ***Thank you*** for posting a usable data source: it makes questions so much more pleasant to answer
- It's pretty much essential to check whether the HTTP request has succeeded, and die with an explanatory message if there was a problem. It's just an extra statement

  ```
  die $response->{reason} unless $response->{success};
  ```

Here's how I would write your code. Instead of selecting the field as you do I have used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump)
to display the contents of the structure

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use HTTP::Tiny;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS 'decode_json';

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'); 

die $response->{reason} unless $response->{success};

my $data = decode_json $response->{content};

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

#### output

```
{
  completed => bless(do{\(my $o = 0)}, "JSON::PP::Boolean"),
  id => 1,
  title => "delectus aut autem",
  userId => 1,
}
```

As you can see, `$content->[0]->{name}` would never work because the data is a *hash* rather than an array, and there is no hash key `name` anywhere. But the Latin is a strong indicator that the server has been updated since your question so this is not a problem

The value `$data->{completed}` is boolean, and should probably be tested with

```
if ( $data->{completed} ) { ... }
```

to decide what to do with the response

Comment: Cpanel::JSON::XS is the fastest and least buggy JSON module on CPAN, it's true, it's the default module used by JSON::MaybeXS that was mentioned.

Comment: @Grinnz: Sure, but `JSON::MaybeXS` will take its pick from only those modules that are installed. Because it doesn't begin with `JSON`, `Cpanel::JSON::XS` is often overlooked and is less likely to be available.

Comment: It gets pulled in as a dependency unless a pure-perl installation is requested.